# read.csv removes negative sign with parenthesis i.e. (text) and as.numeric changes this to NA

Tags: r

Based on the data below, when I bring in a CSV with a column with negative values (datatype text), R removes the negative sign and adds parenthesis as shown in the `dput()` below. So when I convert the datatype from `text` to `numeric` using `as.numeric` or `as.integer`, the function converts these negative values to `NA`.

How can I change the datatype to numeric such that it includes the negative numbers as well?
Or rather how can I import a CSV such that the negative values get carried over as is.

Data:

```
structure(list(`% Change Business Establishments` = c("7.6", 
"6.4", "9.4", "7.9", "14.1", "11.0", "DATA NOT AVAILABLE", "33.9", 
"10.5", "8.2", "11.5", "24.8", "(16.7)", "(1.2)", "(1.0)", "7.7", 
"8.5", "1.6", "0.0", "(10.7)", "5.0", "10.5", "10.3", "(2.7)", 
"16.0", "(4.3)", "15.5", "13.3", "1.3", "13.8", "83.5", "9.9", 
"0.0", "8.0", "15.8", "(2.9)", "2.1", "32.8", "3.6", "35.8", 
"0.0", "24.4", "(13.3)", "(1.4)", "14.5", "12.7", "1.8", "10.2", 
"5.6", "3.3", "28.1", "5.1", "23.8", "4.7", "12.1", "12.3", "10.3", 
"0.0", "20.6", "21.0", "13.9", "0.0", "(18.8)", "14.2", "13.1", 
"8.3", "(1.1)", "7.4", "2.8", "56.9", "23.0", "13.7", "6.1", 
"5.0", "9.3", "(0.1)", "13.6", "12.9", "29.0", "(16.2)", "24.0", 
"35.3", "0.0", "12.3", "(3.3)", "2.2", "7.9", "4.6", "3.4", "3.7", 
"2.3", "4.0", "4.0", "(18.0)", "7.4", "6.3", "12.0", "9.2", "1.6", 
"12.2")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Data in MS-Excel:

[image]

Comment: `df_sample = read_csv("path/file.csv")` or  `df_sample = read.csv("path/file.csv")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change how the file was saved, here's a way to modify it in R:

```
library(dplyr)
df = df |>
  mutate(
    `% Change Business Establishments` = sub(pattern = "(", replacement = "-", fixed = TRUE, x = `% Change Business Establishments`),
    `% Change Business Establishments` = sub(pattern = ")", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE, x = `% Change Business Establishments`),
    `% Change Business Establishments` = as.numeric(`% Change Business Establishments`)
  )

print(df, n = 100)
# # A tibble: 100 × 1
#     `% Change Business Establishments`
#                                  <dbl>
#   1                                7.6
#   2                                6.4
#   3                                9.4
#   4                                7.9
#   5                               14.1
#   6                               11  
#   7                               NA  
#   8                               33.9
#   9                               10.5
#  10                                8.2
#  11                               11.5
#  12                               24.8
#  13                              -16.7
#  14                               -1.2
#  15                               -1  
#  ...
```

Comment: Oh I see if the dataset was an `xls` instead `csv` then I wouldn't have seen such behavior while importing the Excel dataset.

Comment: Exactly, what you've got is a CSV saved in one of Excel's number formats (accounting, or something) instead of a standard format. If you import directly from Excel, it would work without extra steps. (The `readxl` package usually works easily.)

Comment: Yeah actually this column is shown as `General` in `Excel` because it also contains a `string value`. Good to know, thank you so much for the quick response.